# Can't make sort_value works.

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to order my groupby, but I dont know what is wrong.

This is my code:

```
    operacionesgender = {
    'PurchaseID' : 'count',
    'Price' : ['mean','sum']
}
Opergender = df.groupby('Gender').agg(operacionesgender)
print (Opergender.sort_values(by='count').head(5))
```

I tried in several differents ways, but none works.

Comment: Please show the sample dataset

Answer (score 0):

You are created a multiple index in `columns`

```
Opergender.sort_values(('PurchaseID','count'))
```